# Location Updates in Android requestLocationUpdates method

Tags: java, android, gps, location

I have what might be a very simple, silly question about the requestLocationUpdates method for a LocationManager object.

My understanding is that requestLocationUpdates actually makes the request to the provider to send for an updated location? Why then are we passing a LocationListener callback to a request?

Seems like the entire point of a LocationListener is to pick up changes in the location when the location provider decides it is time to update. So is the requestLocationUpdates a search function to see if the providers have looked for and found a new location or is it an actual request that triggers the providers into activity that actively looks for a new location?

I would add that I did read the docs and I'm still unclear about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My understanding is that requestLocationUpdates actually makes the request to the provider to send for an updated location?

Yes.

> Why then are we passing a LocationListener callback to a request?

How else were you planning on getting the updates? There's a `PendingIntent` flavor of `requestLocationUpdates()` if you would prefer it.

> Seems like the entire point of a LocationListener is to pick up changes in the location when the location provider decides it is time to update.

Correct.

> So is the requestLocationUpdates a search function to see if the providers have looked for and found a new location

No.

> is it an actual request that triggers the providers into activity that actively looks for a new location?

Yes.

Bear in mind that GPS, in particular, is powered down unless some app calls something like `requestLocationUpdates()` to retrieve data from the GPS provider.